# Application Error in heroku (using play framework)

Tags: mongodb, heroku, playframework

I'm using play-1.2.4 framework in java and using MongoDB database. Pushing the project in heroku repositary successfully.
And try to open my page, I still see an Error: Application Error

```
An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. Please try again in a few moments.

If you are the application owner, check your logs for details.
```

When i enter this `heroku logs` command, getting the following error

```
heroku logs
   2012-05-05T06:00:13+00:00 app[web.1]: ~        _            _
2012-05-05T06:00:13+00:00 app[web.1]: ~  _ __ | | __ _ _  _| |
2012-05-05T06:00:13+00:00 app[web.1]: ~ |  __/|_|\____|\__ (_)
2012-05-05T06:00:13+00:00 app[web.1]: ~ | '_ \| |/ _' | || |_|
2012-05-05T06:00:13+00:00 app[web.1]: ~ |_|            |__/
2012-05-05T06:00:13+00:00 app[web.1]: ~
2012-05-05T06:00:13+00:00 app[web.1]: ~ play! 1.2.4, http://www.p
layframework.org
2012-05-05T06:00:13+00:00 app[web.1]: ~ framework ID is prod
2012-05-05T06:00:13+00:00 app[web.1]: ~ Ctrl+C to stop
2012-05-05T06:00:13+00:00 app[web.1]: ~
2012-05-05T06:00:13+00:00 app[web.1]: ~
2012-05-05T06:00:13+00:00 app[web.1]:
2012-05-05T06:00:14+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with stat
us 0
2012-05-05T06:00:14+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from start
ing to crashed
2012-05-05T06:05:17+00:00 heroku[run.1]: State changed from creat
ed to starting
2012-05-05T06:05:19+00:00 app[run.1]: Awaiting client
2012-05-05T06:05:20+00:00 heroku[run.1]: State changed from start
ing to up
2012-05-05T06:05:49+00:00 app[run.1]: Error R13 (Attach error) ->
 Failed to attach to process
2012-05-05T06:05:50+00:00 heroku[run.1]: Process exited with stat
us 1
2012-05-05T06:05:50+00:00 heroku[run.1]: State changed from up to
 complete
```

When i run heroku process using `heroku ps`, it shows me that

```
Process  State           Command
-------  --------------  ------------------------------------
web.1    crashed for 5m  play run --http.port=$PORT $PLAY_O..
```

When i run `heroku run console`, it shows me an following error:

Running console attached to terminal...

```
C:/Program Files/Heroku/l ib/heroku/client/rendezvous.rb:33:in `initialize': A connection a ttempt failed because the connected party did not properly respon d after a period of time, or established connection failed becaus e connected host has failed to respond. - connect(2) (Errno::ETIM EDOUT)
        from C:/Program Files/Heroku/lib/heroku/client/rendezvous .rb:33:in `open'
        from C:/Program Files/Heroku/lib/heroku/client/rendezvous .rb:33:in `block in start'
        from C:/Program Files/ruby-1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/timeout.r b:58:in `timeout'
        from C:/Program Files/Heroku/lib/heroku/client/rendezvous .rb:27:in `start'
        from C:/Program Files/Heroku/lib/heroku/command/run.rb:35 :in `index'
        from C:/Program Files/Heroku/lib/heroku/command.rb:148:in  `run'
        from C:/Program Files/Heroku/lib/heroku/cli.rb:9:in `star t'
        from C:/Program Files/Heroku/bin/heroku:28:in `<main>'
```

What i missed here? Can anyone help me to sort this out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to run Play in `%prod` mode on Heroku.  Make sure you have `--%prod` in your `Procfile`.  Here is a sample `Procfile`:

```
web:    play run -Xmx256M --%prod --http.port=$PORT -Dprecompiled=true
```

Comment: My procfile  contain this "web: play run --http.port=$PORT $PLAY_OPTS
"I run the port number and the play options from "heroku logs".

Comment: The problem is that you are running in dev mode and in dev mode Play listens on a Java debug port.  On Heroku your app can only listen on one port and your app is trying to listen on two.  So perhaps your `application.conf` somehow is setup to for debugging in prod mode.

Comment: conf/application.conf file having application.mode=dev instead i write %production.application.mode=prod.But it remains the same

Comment: You need: `%prod.application.mode=prod` Here is an example: https://github.com/jamesward/playbars/blob/master/conf/application.conf